# Execute commands without sudo inside jenkins

Tags: sudo, root, jenkins

I've imported a bunch of jenkins jobs and these jobs have a lot of shell script commands.There are no sudo before these commands.Jenkins has its own user.Is there a way so I can execute these commands through jenkins without having to write sudo before each command?

Comment: Some commands are requiring root privileges and some are not. Pls post list of command to get more accurate answer

Comment: for example "rm , touch , mkdir".

Comment: @Khafaga, none of mentioned above commands need special privileges if you work in directories, owned by jenkins user. And IMHO I do not see any reason to want to do something outside jenkins

Answer (score 0):

The user that's used in the build step is the user that was used to connect the slave. (For the master, it's the user id under which the master is running).

So, create a slave that connects via ssh as the user that you need (possibly to localhost), and then run the jobs on that slave.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file under /etc/sudoers.d/. And You can add specific commands in that file with path and NOPASSWD.

`username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/chown tomcat.tomcat /home/harry/*
 username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mkdir /home/harry/*`

For arguments,

`username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mkdir * /home/harry/*`

Same you can give any command like this and execute them without passwd in jenkins. Remember, the username will be the jenkins username which we are using to execute over the ssh or on same master server.